# Light fitting plastered into ceiling

Tags: repair, light-fixture, plaster, stuck

Hoping someone can help...

I recently had some plaster work done throughout my house. Skimming on the walls and new board on the ceiling.

Annoyingly, the chap has plastered around the light fittings to the point where they won't come undone. They are officially now part of my ceiling!

[image: Image of lighting fixture submerged in plaster]

Any ideas of how I can fix this without destroying the ceiling?

Cheers

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some more info, and a better picture would help.

Comment: Do you need to replace it? if not, why do anything?

Answer (score 3):

Use a knife to cut into the plaster at the base of the fixture. Then when you remove the fixture, it will come off at the cut line and not pull any ceiling plaster off with it.